# Is it possible to change FormUrls in an ContentType after deployment?

Tags: 2013, content-type

we are currently using a custom ContentType for deploying a custom list with custom forms for the new, edit and display page.

```
  <ContentType ID="... >
    <FieldRefs></FieldRefs>
    <XmlDocuments>
      <XmlDocument NamespaceURI="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
        <FormUrls xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/v3/contenttype/forms/url">
          <Display>_layouts/Company.sharepoint.solution/ItemForm.aspx?mode=display</Display>
          <Edit>_layouts/Company.sharepoint.solution/ItemForm.aspx?mode=edit</Edit>
          <New>_layouts/Company.sharepoint.solution/ItemForm.aspx?mode=new</New>
        </FormUrls>
      </XmlDocument>
    </XmlDocuments>
  </ContentType>
```

But now through customers new requirements, the Name of _layouts Folder should Change from

> _layouts/Company.sharepoint.solution

to

> _layouts/solutionname

My question: how can i can Change this URL in the contenttype and deploy it to the production Environment? Is this possible to Change this after a contenttype is already deployed and in use?

br
Yavuz

Answer (score 0):

Can you use SharePoint Designer? 
If yes, open the list, click in your Content Type and you will see an area to modify this.

Comment: I would do it programmatically or better deployable!